# Best practice for validating input in Express/Mongoose app (controllers and models)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to node/express/mongoose and backend in general, and I'm building an API from the ground up.

I split my code into controllers and DAOs (mongoose models) and I'm not sure where validation should be taking place, what exactly should the controller and model each be doing?

For example, for the route GET /users/:id, I want it to:

- Return 400 if the id given is not a valid ObjectId
- Return 404 if the id is a valid ObjectId, but no documents exist with this id
- Return 200 if a document is found, and remove some fields (password, __v, and _id (because I made a virtual field "id" without underscore)) before sending the response
- Return 500 otherwise

Here's what I tried. It's currently doing everything I want above, but I'm not sure if it's the best implementation:

**users.controller.js**

```
const UserModel = require('../models/users.model')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

exports.getById = async (req, res) => {
    // Check that the id is a valid ObjectId
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid ObjectID' })
    }

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findById(req.params.id)

        if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'No user with this ID' })

        res.status(200).send(user)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
}
```

**users.model.js**

```
exports.findById = async (id) => {
    let user = await User.findById(id)

    if (!user) {
        return null
    }

    user = user.toJSON()
    delete user._id
    delete user.__v
    delete user.password
    return user
}
```

Is this the best way to structure things? Please critique and suggest any improvements and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do all validation and logic in Controllers file and helpers classes in separate small js files.
Also trying to keep the models as lean as possible. Actually you can create different middleware functions to validate some inputs.
It is also helpful to create ErrorResponse middleware so you can do such simple and easy to read validations as:

```
if (!userFromDB) throw new ErrorResponse({code: 404, msg: "User doesn't exist"})
```

than catch it and handle in separate file with different options of the answer.

Backend has 100+ ways of implementing it. You need to choose you own

Comment: I was mainly concerned about the model, which as you said, I would prefer if it were kept as lean as possible. So I've moved those "delete" lines to the controller and removed that if statement, which reduced the model's findById function to simply fetch and return the user (or nothing if there isn't a user with that id).

Comment: That's right, also consider to remove the fields by projection, to not explicitly remove them in the controller